# Can not make work python in windows 7 64 bits

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, python

Tried installing python 3.13 64 bits, 3.13 32 bits and 2.7 64 bits. But none of them seems to work.

Both 3.13 after installing it I run python.exe and it shows:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
ImportError: No module named encodings.utf_8
```

and when i run python.exe (2.7 version) it prints:

`No module named site`

i don't know what else to do. i searched everywhere, but it seems no one had the same error.

I am running it on windows 7 64 bits Home Premium.
Anything you need to know just ask me.

Answer (score 2):

It was relatedd to Environment variables, but it was a previous aptana install that asigned a strange value to PYTHONHOME. Uninstalled all python, erased all python related variables, reinstalled and rebooted. now it seems to work =)